# Get Jetty to send the correct SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, jetty, keystore

I have created a Keystore and imported my certificate (issued by an official CA) into it using keytool, no problems there.

Next, I start up Jetty (v. 8.0.0 M3) and give it the location of the keystore using the `-DjettySslKeyStoreFile` parameter, Jetty starts up fine, runs on port 443 too.

When I go to https://site.com however, the certificate I get is invalid. When examining the certificate, it seems Jetty forwards the information I entered when generating the keystore (using keytool -genkey), instead of the information contained in the certificate itself.

What do I need to do so that Jetty sends the certificate found inside the keystore, instead of the data stored in the keystore? I wasn't able to find any documentation on this. I would expect that you'd give the certificate a specific alias when inserting it into the keystore, or that you can configure what alias Jetty should serve.

Comment: 8.0.0 M3, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never actually figured this out. Instead, we went for an nginx SSL proxy in front of it, which - functionally - works just as well, and with this we get support and setup from our hosting party as well.